# Masstransit V8 Testing How to config UseDelayedMessageScheduler()

Tags: testing, .net-6.0, masstransit, state-machine

I just upgrade my state machine saga projects to DotNet6 and Masstransit version 8.0.5.

Some how I can't find any way to config delay message schedule in my unit testing.

version 7.3.0

```
var provider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddMassTransitInMemoryTestHarness(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddSagaStateMachine<OldSaga, OldState>()
                .InMemoryRepository();
            cfg.AddSagaTestHarness<OldState>();
        })
        .BuildServiceProvider(true);
var harness = provider.GetRequiredService<InMemoryTestHarness>();
        harness.OnConfigureInMemoryBus += configurator =>
        {
            configurator.UseDelayedMessageScheduler();
        };
var sagaHarness = provider.GetRequiredService<ISagaTestHarness<OldState>>();
```

Version 8.0.5

```
var provider = new ServiceCollection().AddMassTransitTestHarness(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddSagaStateMachine<NewSaga, NewState>();
        })
        .BuildServiceProvider(true);
var harness = provider.GetTestHarness();
var sagaHarness = harness.GetSagaStateMachineHarness<NewSaga,NewState>();


**cfg.AddSagaTestHarness<NewState>(); is obsolete**
```

and can't `GetRequiredService<InMemoryTestHarness>();`

Answer (score 0):

The changes [are documented](https://masstransit-project.com/getting-started/upgrade-v6.html#version-8). The delayed message scheduler is added by default unless you specify your own transport configuration for the test harness. The `AddXxxHarness` are no longer required – the harnesses are automatically added by the underlying test harness.